# Debian: convert from RAID1 to RAID 0

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, disk, raid

i have a debian11 ssd server which is installed in **RAID 1 MIRRORING**

i use the server as webhost and for better performance (whith high volume of users) i need to use RAID 0 so data wil be split across 2 drivers

2 x 1TB disks

> QUESTION IS: **How to convert from RAID 1 to RAID 0 without reinstalling**
> the server

Comment: You understand that because you are using SSDs you are unlikely to get significantly better performance with RAID0 than RAID1, but in return you are significantly increasing the probability that your filesystem will die due to a disk failure (possibly as much as x4)?

Comment: For practical purposes it's impossible to do it live, and I presume you have some sort of hosting provider which means you can reinstall the server using RAID0.

TLDR: You cannot, you need to reinstall.

Comment: Also, RAID 0 only improves *write* performance for *large* files, neither of which are your problems in a web service. Bulk read performance for RAID 0 and RAID 1 is the same (both allow interleaving reads from both drives), and random access read performance will be better for RAID 1 because reads can be sent to the less busy drive.

Comment: Did you do some analysis to find out what's the bottleneck in your case? SSD? Network? CPU?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I believe it's possible: split the mirror and then append the now-spare disk as a non-interleaved extension to what is half a RAID1. Whether it's possible to do it satisfactorily without a reboot I'm not sure, but I wouldn't want to try it. Without the interleaving there's little point as there's be next to no performance increase

Comment: @SimonRichter Richter thanks for yout answer. so as i understeand from your comment. better is to have raid1 because   users will read data from both disks

Comment: RAID1 isn't just about improving performance due to two read subsystems, it's also about maintaining integrity of the service when one of the SSDs decides to die

Comment: *Whether it's possible to do it satisfactorily without a reboot I'm not sure, but I wouldn't want to try it.* - exactly. Also, enlighten me how you're going to move the root FS :-) There's `switch_root` of course but oh boy I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'd leave it on the remaining half. I'm not advocating this at all, mind - I don't see anyone exactly jumping up and down to say it's a good idea

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have to agree with roaima. A raid1 md array can be changed to raid0 without destroying the data. A reboot will be required but the OP never daid that would be a problem. I have to also agree with almost everyone that this change is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my (unfortunately deleted post) I showed the results of testing mdadam (included in Debian) RAID1, RAID0, RAID10, and single disk. The expected RAID1 performance -slightly slower write speed than single disk and nearly same read speed as RAID0- was not observed. After a deep search on the Internet I found an explanation that it is not an error, but a feature. The reason is to give kernel a chance to do two parallel reads for two independent program.
This is not the case in the BSD unix (FreeBSD, NET-BSD, OpenBSD) while it does not use mdadam subsystem.
But I must agree that while using SSD the disk performance (RAID0,1 none) may not be your main problem.
You did not described the server component: web-server (Apache/Lighttp/...), application module (PHP/python/...), database (mysql/postgres/...), number of CPU cores, amount of RAM, what kind of services it realises (static pages/dynamic pages/heavy downloads/...)

If I strictly answer your question: migration from RAID1 to RAID0 cannot be realised on-line. You have to stop the server, make backup to an external disk, then reconfigure the RAID0. It could be more easy, if you have some independent system disk. If not, you must reconfigure the RAID while installing the new Linux OS.

But with respect to **comments** above, it is highly recommended **NOT** to do this. The RAID1 is mainly used on server for better data protection.